# Trying to understand npm for frontend development

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I'm self-teaching Javascript/Node development. I understand how npm installs packages for the Node app which runs on the server. What I can't wrap my head around is how npm helps me with the frontend, e.g. if I npm install leaflet I install it on the server side, in the Node app, right? How does that help me with the frontend then?

Comment: Nope it isn't installed on the server side. NPM packages can be used clientside as well. Bundlers like rollup and webpack bundle it into a single or multiple js file that you load onto the client browser given that you're installing it in something like a Create React App Setup

Comment: NPM on the frontend is entirely separate from the backend. You use it to download packages from the web (npm install) and to create a build JS file for your online product (npm run build).

Comment: Of course. I totally didn't realize that. My head was just spinning around node and trying to understand how to make the node app work in the frontend. But naturally, it's 2 different things. The frontend and the backend. The frontend CAN be served by node but it doesn't NEED to be. It doesn't even need to be in the same folder on the development machine - not even on the same machine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I can't wrap my head around is how npm helps me with the frontend,

Many modules available through npm will work on the client-side.

Using a package manager like npm allows you to track which modules you are using (they are recorded in `package.json`, get security updates (`npm audit`) and upgrade them (`npm install foo@latest`).

A bundler such as Webpack, Parcel, Browserify, or Rollup will take your JS (which uses ES6 or CommonJS modules) and follow the dependencies (i.e. what you `import` or `require`) to the installed modules from NPM and bundle everything up into a file (or files) suitable for running in a browser.

Generally you will build a toolchain that doesn't **just** bundle JS modules but also runs linting, converts SASS to CSS, generates different versions of image files (for use with `srcset`) and so on.

> e.g. if I npm install leaflet I install it on the server side, in the Node app, right? How does that help me with the frontend then?

Note that this happens during development (usually with hot reloading) and at at build time (often in a CI system) and not on demand (so it doesn't run server-side).

Comment: So, to stay with my example of leaflet - to get a leaflet that I installed with npm to the client side, I still need a "bundler" which will create something I can point a webserver, such as express, to?

Comment: The best way to understand would be to pick a bundler and follow its introductory tutorial.